# How can I find the full path of a DLL without actually calling LoadLibrary?

Tags: windows, dll

If I call `LoadLibrary("foo.dll")`, it will look in various locations on the system, choose the best match, and load that library. I would like to find the full path to this file *before* actually loading it. Is there a simple way to do this? My google-fu has thus far failed me, but it seems intuitive there is some function to do this. My current solution is to actually call `LoadLibraryEx` with the `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE` flag, then `GetModuleFileName` on the result; after this I assume I would have to release the library and reload it without this flag, but this seems like a roundabout method.  Is there a better way? `ResolvePathFromDllName` perhaps?

Comment: If you've used `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE` "you cannot call functions like `GetModuleFileName`, `GetModuleHandle` or `GetProcAddress` with this DLL" [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684179(v=vs.85).aspx]

Comment: Hmm, it works for me, but I think the dependent DLL is actually already loaded by the time I call `LoadLibraryEx` with `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE`. Maybe the deprecated `DONT_RESOLVE_DLL_REFERENCES` is the way to go...

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`SearchPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365527%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but if you're planning on actually calling `LoadLibrary` later it's not recommended (see the `Remarks` section on the linked page (and quoted below in this answer) regarding possibly returning the wrong results).

Note also that the search order is slightly different than that of `LoadLibrary`, because it doesn't make the same presumptions at the start of the search that are documented in `LoadLibrary`. It strictly searches the `PATH` as its documentation says it does; it doesn't automatically look first in the same folders. See the paragraph in `Remarks`:

> The **SearchPath** function is not recommended as a method of locating a .dll file if the intended use of the output is in a call to the [LoadLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. This can result in locating the wrong .dll file because the search order of the **SearchPath** function differs from the search order used by the **LoadLibrary** function. If you need to locate and load a .dll file, use the **LoadLibrary** function.

So the proper answer to this question would be to use `LoadLibrary` in the first place (as you are) to make sure you're finding the same DLL you'll be loading later.

Comment: I believe my implementation is flawed, based on Eugen's comment

Comment: I meant "LoadLibrary, as you're now doing"; I didn't mean using `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE`. Sorry - should have been more clear.